# How to parse a XML and update it when we are complicated hericarchy?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Suppose I am having following XML File content

```
<CREDENTIALS>
   <SCENERIOONE> 
      <USERNAME>stackoverflow</USERNAME>
      <PASSWORD>argmishra</PASSWORD>
   </SCENERIOONE>
   <SCENERIOTWO> 
      <USERNAME>stackexchnage</USERNAME>
      <PASSWORD>mishraarg</PASSWORD>
   </SCENERIOTWO>
</CREDENTIALS>
```

I want to retrieve the data for SCENERIOONE(Username and password) and check it and update it if required and similarly for SCENERIOTWO.

I am able to retrieve data if i replaced SCENERIOTWO with SCENERIOONE i.e. child node of CREDENTIALS are same.

But not able to retrieve if child node of one parent node is different.

EDIT:

Now I am able to retrieve the Data from XML by passing Scenario's:-

```
try {
  File file = new File("D://DemoWorkSpace//XMLDemo//lib//MyXMLFile.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = db.parse(file);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("MEMBER_BENEFITS");
  System.out.println("Information of all employees");

  for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

    Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

    if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
      NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("USERNAME");
      Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
      NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
      System.out.println("User Name : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
      NodeList lstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("PASSWORD");
      Element lstNmElmnt = (Element) lstNmElmntLst.item(0);
      NodeList lstNm = lstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
      System.out.println("Password : " + ((Node) lstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
    }

  }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

But I do not know how to update the XML file?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, what you're really after is the username/password nodes, regardless of where they are in the document....

You can use XPath to query the document to return what you want, for example...

```
try (InputStream is = TestXML.class.getResourceAsStream("/Credentials.xml")){

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = db.parse(is);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    XPathExpression xExpress = xpath.compile("//*[USERNAME and PASSWORD]/*");
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xExpress.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {

        Node node = nodeList.item(index);
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

    }

} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Will output...

```
USERNAME
PASSWORD
USERNAME
PASSWORD
```

If it's important, you can use the `Node`s `parent` property to find the parent node and obviously, `getTextContent` to get the nodes text content

You can manipulate the nodes like normal, based on your needs

**Updated**

So, based on comments, you should be able to do something like...

```
try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = db.parse(new File("Credentials.xml"));
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    String scenerio = "SCENERIOONE";

    XPathExpression xExpress = xpath.compile("/CREDENTIALS/" + scenerio + "/[USERNAME and PASSWORD]/*");
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xExpress.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {

        Node node = nodeList.item(index);
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

    }

} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which will return the `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` nodes for `SCENERIOONE`

You can use `node.get/setTextContent` to get/set the text as per normal.

And when you need to, you can use something like...

```
Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("Credentials.xml"));
tf.transform(dom, result);
```

To save it...

Comment: Thanks for Answer But i want some thing different. I want to retrieve data in mentioned form:-      ScenerioONE password and username then ScenerioTWO username and password and so on

Comment: @AnuragMishra Good, can you describe it better because I have no idea what you want...

Comment: So that i can check whether credentials for scenario one is correct  or not. ID correct then OK but not then replace with new one stored in a string.

Comment: So you only want to look at the credentials in scenario one?  Then what does scenario two have to do with anything?

Comment: The situation is something like this user selected the scenario one  then i will check the credentials present in XML file with user entered. If both are same then its ok but different i will update the credentials file with user credentials. I will do this for n number of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
$server_output = "<CREDENTIALS>
<SCENERIOONE> 
  <USERNAME>stackoverflow</USERNAME>
  <PASSWORD>argmishra</PASSWORD>
</SCENERIOONE>
<SCENERIOTWO> 
  <USERNAME>stackexchnage</USERNAME>
  <PASSWORD>mishraarg</PASSWORD>
</SCENERIOTWO>
</CREDENTIALS>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($server_output);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);


foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $username = $value['USERNAME'];
   $password = $value['PASSWORD'];
}

Here is the output:
stackoverflow
argmishra
stackexchnage
mishraarg
```

Comment: whoa... where is Java in this solution?

Comment: Actually you didn't mention java in question. Above solution is for php.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov The question is marked as java/xml-parsing